# How to overwrite Form Templates in CakePHP3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've some problems in overwriting default templates in CakePHps FormHelper.
As explained [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html) one could simply use the "setTemplates"-method to use customized div wrappers.

However, when I add

```
$this->Form->setTemplates(['inputContainer' => '<div class="custom-class">{{content}}</div>']);
```

to my template file, I get some PHP warnings:

> Warning (2): substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
>   [CORE\src\View\Helper\FormHelper.php, line 2455]
>
> Warning (2): explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
>   [CORE\src\View\Helper\FormHelper.php, line 2459]
>
> Warning (2): array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
>   [CORE\src\View\Helper\FormHelper.php, line 2460]

It seems as there is an internal problem in the FormViewHelper.
Or did I miss something out?

Comment: Please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: ver3.3.14... didn't checked that. thx

Answer (score 2):

Just as mentioned in documentation if you are using prior version than cakephp 3.4, Just do:

```
 $myTemplates = [
   'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-control">{{content}}</div>',
 ];

 // Prior to 3.4
 $this->Form->templates($myTemplates);
```

This is for versions 3.4 and later:

```
 // versions 3.4 and later
 $this->Form->setTemplates($myTemplates);
```

See Here ([Customizing the Templates FormHelper Uses in CakePHP 3](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses))